# Why to use temporary variable to hold the input number while checking palindrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, if-statement, palindrome

Below is the python program that checks whether the given input is a palindrome.

```
num=int(input("Enter number:"))
temp = num
reverse=0
while(num>0):
    digit=num%10
    reverse=(reverse*10)+digit
    num=num//10
if reverse == temp:
    print("Palindrome")
else:
    print("Not Palindrome")
```

When I replace 'temp' as 'num' in 'if condition'( if reverse == num: ), the output will be wrong.

```
num=int(input("Enter number:"))
reverse=0
while(num>0):
    digit=num%10
    reverse=(reverse*10)+digit
    num=num//10
if reverse == num:
    print("Palindrome")
else:
    print("Not Palindrome")
```

Why does it return the output as "Not Palindrome"? Why do we use temporary variable to hold the input 'num'?

Comment: `print(num)` before and after the loop…?!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are changing this variable in a cycle here `num=num//10` and after cycle compare changed variable:

for more understandable add prints:

```
num=int(input("Enter number:"))
temp = num
reverse=0
while(num>0):
    digit=num%10
    reverse=(reverse*10)+digit
    num=num//10
    print(f'{num=}, {reverse=}, {temp=}')
if reverse == temp:
    print("Palindrome")
else:
    print("Not Palindrome")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop, check the line

```
num=num//10
```

*num* is divided by 10 and replaces the old value of *num*. So *num* is getting updated in each loop.

Say you start with 4554 as the input, which is the initial value of *num*, but this will change in each loop into 455, then 45, then 4 and finally 0, at which point the loops ends.

So, the value of *num* is lost in the process of finding the digits. To be able to preserve the initial value, *num* is saved in *temp*.

You will almost always get "Not Palindrome" if you try with you try to use *num* instead of *temp* in the conditional, because *num* at this point will always be zero. If your initial value is zero, you would get "Palindrome".

Answer (score 0):

This is because the num variable is not the original number, as it has been modified in the while loop:

```
num=num//10
```

the num variable has been worked with and reduced down to <= 0 as the while loop repeats itself until condition of num >0 is met.

Using temp variable to store the original number is needed to compare the reverse variable with at the end, to check if the reversed number matches the original number.